# Button image sides cropped

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to fit image to button perfectly.
But the image is cropped on its right and bottom faces, see attached print screen:
[image]

I edited the button as follows:

```
var l_oStopImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\AmitL\Downloads\Button-2-stop-icon72p.png");
var l_oStopPic = new Bitmap(l_oStopImage , new Size(btnStopOperation.Width, btnStopOperation.Height));
btnStopOperation.Image = l_oStopPic ;
btnStopOperation.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

btnStopOperation.TabStop = false;
btnStopOperation.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
btnStopOperation.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
```

I also tried to edit the `BackgroundImageLayout` but none of the `ImageLayouts` fixed the problem..

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your button `width` and `height` the same as your image width and height?

Comment: STRETCH:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelayout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No I didn't even checked its dimensions I figured it should fit to the dimensions  of the button..

Comment: Thomas - ImageLayouts  stretch doesn't fix the crope..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: backgroundimage]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWBKk.png)https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelayout(v=vs.110).aspx

You should use stretch, I suggest in designtime (this is not java where you have to add elements by code):

```
            this.buttonOk.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
            this.buttonOk.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("buttonOk.BackgroundImage")));
            this.buttonOk.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.buttonOk.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.buttonOk.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(475, 15);
            this.buttonOk.Name = "buttonOk";
            this.buttonOk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            this.buttonOk.TabIndex = 11;
            this.buttonOk.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.buttonOk.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonOk_Click);
```

And it will work, done it many times before

I got this code from my own working Form1.Designer.cs but because of that: please use the Visual Studio designer and don't try to write all this code / logic in your constructor or something.

Comment: Thanks that helped just need to remove the border now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are showing an image with the same size as your button.

When you want an image fit in your button, the width and height of image should be at least 1 point less than your button size. (or in other word, you can set your button width and height 1 point more than the image size).

So you can change your code to this:

```
var l_oStopPic = new Bitmap(l_oStopImage ,
    new Size(btnStopOperation.Width-1, btnStopOperation.Height-1));
```